# Error importing blocks after upgrading to v0.9.32

Tags: polkadot, validator, nodes, client

After upgrading the node to v0.9.32 I started seeing this error message:

```
2022-11-11 14:03:44  Error importing block 0x2062a73f1dee2fd35ad6ac25c641b08bf94cf6390b9fc7a8480d7b8ea9412eab: consensus error: Import failed: Import failed: Potential long-range attack: block not in finalized chain.    
2022-11-11 14:03:44  Error importing block 0xdab08906a732245b361fd46c55c563be85515375b5b244250346e42592a53688: consensus error: Import failed: Parent block of 0xdab0…3688 has no associated weight    
2022-11-11 14:03:44 Block import error: Potential long-range attack: block not in finalized chain.
```

I downgraded back to v0.9.30 and the error persists. Any ideas on the cause or remedy?

Comment: This post is missing really any kind of information. How did you run the node? When did this  happen? Directly after upgrading? Some point later? We would need more logs etc. How did you close the node before this error happened? I think your db maybe got corrupted somehow.